# Cannot read property of undefined after fetching data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

`p {{ points.returnPoints }}`

returns in my html

```
[ { "description": null, "id": "ade5e33e-658f-4a9d-84f9-590357600054", "name": "Starting Point", "position": { "lat": -0.00027894973753803614, "lon": -0.01857362687587738 }, "radius": 100, "sort": 0 } ]
```

but, whenever I do on my button `v-if="points.returnPoints[0].name !=` Starting Point`"

`I am getting this error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Why am I getting this error? I must hide visibility of my item, based on first array element's name and I am not able to do it because of this error. How do I fix this?

In my component I am calling GET request for the pointList array.

My getter:

```js
  getters: {
    returnPoints(state) {
      let sortState = [...state.pointList.collection]
      return sortState.sort((a,b) => a.sort - b.sort)
    },
  }
```

Comment: returnPoints is undefined at some point. Not *after* fetching data but most likely *before*.

Comment: Please provide more context, like the entire component template because there is no way we can help with that :/

It's pretty sure `points.returnPoints` is an empty array by the time you call it. That being said, you should access more safely your data (making assertions that the array is not empty etc.)

Comment: @Kapcash but I am calling the function to fetch data onBeforeMount.. how come its still undefined?

Comment: The element displays in html, but not when I go deeper like `[0].name` or `.id`

Comment: That's surely because your fetch function is asynchronous. Vue component hooks are synchronous, so it doesn't actually wait for your call to mount the component. That's why it has to be "null" safe: your initial state is empty, and later on it's filled in.

Answer (score 3):

> Cannot read property of undefined after fetching data?

In fact, it happens before the data is fetched, because the data is not present when the component gets rendered: `points.returnPoints[0]` is undefined and trying to access the `name` property results in an error.

Try this instead:

```
<div v-if="points.returnPoints.length && points.returnPoints[0].name !== 'Starting Point'"> ... </div>
```

The code above assumes that `points.returnPoints` is an array. If it's empty, the second condition won't be checked and it won't result in an error.

Comment: This eliminated the undefined error, but doesn't display the button, it looks like the .name doesn't load fast enough

Comment: It will render only if `name` is not equal to `Starting Point` and you have only one point in your array with this exact name. So, instead of `!==` do `===`.

Comment: I must not render it if it's not equal to `Starting Point`, I have your exact code, and it doesn't render at all for other items.

Comment: Is your initial state / data initialised with an empty value? If it's undefined, Vue won't react to any changes to even if the array is updated, Vue won't update the component. That's just a lead, maybe not the answer